# Does the EHWPOISON (133) error code cause permanent damage?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, linux-kernel, memory-management, memory-error

Recently, while testing some software on an AAEON UPcore running Ubuntu 16.04, I have encountered exit code 133 EHWPOISON.  I had never heard of it before, and after some research I found this page:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/vm/hwpoison.html

Which seems to imply that every time I see that exit code, a page of memory has been marked "poisoned", and the OS will no longer use that page in the future.

Is this permanent?  If it is, is there a way for me to see how much memory has been poisoned?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think your code 133 means EHWPOISON. A program can return any code it wishes by calling the exit function with the desired code as the argument. Some programs might pass the last errno they received as exit code. I think your 133 means something else. Any of my programs that I wrote print an error message of the errno and then all exit with the error code -1 (or 254). However again any program may do as it pleases. Ive even seen some of them pass a state using the exit code to talk to other programs. I.e 0 means all good 1 means try again etc...

Concerning your EHWPOISON, i have never seen that signal before ever and i had broken ram before. How is the kernel supposed to know that physical memory that has a page mapped to it is broken? Only way is if the hardware tells the kernel "oi mate that section of memory is bad dont use it" normal DDD2/3/4... ram physically cannot do that. ECC Ram however has some hardware functionality which allows it sometimes correct errors or at least detect them if they happen. I have personally only ever seen ecc ram used in systems which have to run 24/7 365 Days a year no matter what. That is usually very specific enterprise hardware, a normal desktop computer/laptop/phone/soc will not have ecc ram. Only other way (I can think of) is if the OS uses the cache in your CPU and somehow detects that whats in ram doesnt make sense. However I am no expert on this but I assume unless the os is actively doing sanity checks comparing cache with main memory I find it highly unlikely that the system could detect that a specific section of main memory is broken. I do not expect such sanity checks to occur when running a program in usermode as that would just waste CPU time. I could be wrong on this but I find it highly unlikely.

Lets assume your hardware is broken and by some mirracle your operating system detects it. At this point i expect your system to become unstable, probably kernel panic. (I have had so many BSOD's back when I was still using Windows due to this)
The only time I had genuently broken ram on a linux system the system behaved like follows. It would halt randomly during usage. (freeze or black screen). It would sometimes not boot up. I do not think that a system with broken main memory can run stable for any longer than 15-30 Minutes.

And yes hadware damage is permanent. Even if just a single byte of ram has gone bad, replace that Ram. In your case, if your general system doesnt seem unstable then I think its highly likely that its something else your program wishes to tell you with code 133. If you want peace of mind just run memtest for an entire night and if it doesnt detect any errors then your good.